# What sets the default parameter value for this MVC3 action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

My MVC 3 app on .NET 4.0 has an `ErrorController` with an action that starts off as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index(Exception error, int? functionId, string viewMessage)
{
   if (error == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewMessage))
      return RedirectPermanent(_DefaultErrorHtm);
   // ...
}
```

I setup no custom routes for this action, but when I request "http://localhost/error", the `error` parameter is not `null` but always a `System.Exception` with no stack trace. What provides this default value, MVC 3 or .NET 4.0? How can I prevent it?

The intended use for this action is that my custom error handler replaces the route dictionary, sets the controller to "Error" and the action to "Index" and provides the correct parameters, and calls `ErrorController.Execute`. Is there a better way to prevent the user from requesting this route directly? `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` does not work because replacing the route dictionary and re-executing the control makes this the parent action.

**UPDATE:** I fought through this by creating a custom route that supplies a default exception my app tests for rather than testing for null. This leads me to suspect it is MVC 3 that supplied the `System.Exception` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second question: put `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` on top of this action - you won't be able to request it from the browser.

Comment: I thought that was a winner, but it won't work because my last paragraph. When I clear the route dictionary and send it to the Error controller, it is no longer a child, so applying this attribute yields a `InvalidOperationException` with the message "The action 'Index' is accessible only by a child request."